# Access to Testable Environment variables

Tags: conditionals

I've figured out how to access environment variables, I can test on a value. I can't test on the value of an environment variable.

I thought it best to include my test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\apar{\par}
\newcommand{\getenva}[1][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value DEV "}{}%
  \ifx\temp\apar\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fred}{m}
  {
      \str_case:nnF { #1 } {
        {BIG}{Scary.}
        {Massive}{Run!}
        }
        {ERROR fred: Invalid case selected in LaTeX doc #1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    test \getenva

    second \fred{BIG}

    third \fred{Massive}

    fourth \fred{\getenva}
\end{document}
```

If you:

```
export DEV=BIG
pdflatex  test_doc.tex
```

Then you get:

```
test BIG
second Scary.
third Run!
fourth ERRORfred:InvalidcaseselectedinLaTeXdocBIG
```

This implies to me that the macro expansion/resolution of getenva is happening after the str_case is evaluated. I've tried to come up with a way to translate the genenva command into latex3 syntax in the hope that would fix the evaluation order, but so far have failed. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The command `\getenva` is not fully expandable, so neither `\fred` can be.

Comment: So is the concept of what I'm trying to do (have content that can be controlled by an environment variable) wrong and something that is not supported, or is it the particular syntax I've stumbled across?